# Sending E-Mails in On-Premises environments? (CSOM)

Tags: 2013, client-object-model, email, provider-hosted-app, authorization

I'm working on an E-Mail function for a SharePoint 2013 provider-hosted App.

The code I'm currently using:

```
// Prepare the E-Mail parameters
EmailProperties properties = new EmailProperties();
properties.Subject = subject;
properties.To = new string[] {toEmailAddress};
properties.Body = "<html><body>" + htmlBodyContent + "</body></html>";
properties.AdditionalHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    {"Reply-To", fromEmailAddress},
    {"Content-Type", "text/html"}
};

// Send the mail over SharePoint
Utility.SendEmail(clientContext, properties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This Code works perfectly in my Office 365 SharePoint Development Site. But it does not work on the Client's on-premises SharePoint.

The `clientContext.ExecuteQuery()` function throws an ServerUnauthorizedException , telling me that the Access was Denied for the operation.

The App has the same Permissions in the O365 SP as it has in the on-premises SP. Also both SharePoint Servers have a working outgoing E-Mail configuration and are both able to send E-Mails to Users.

Are there any differences between sending Emails in on-prem SharePoints and sending them in an Office 365 SharePoints? Which permissions does the sending of E-Mails require?